# 403 in nginx when accessing a directory

Tags: nginx, domain, redirect, url

I made a very simple server to test how a URL with folder behaves in nginx. Nginx is running in docker (nginx:latest image). Nginx runs user `nginx` (default set in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`).

```
server {
        server_name example.com;

        location /test/ {
                root /var/www/test;
                index index.html;
        }
}
```

and this structure:

```
/var/www
└── test
    └── index.html

cat /var/www/test/index.html
Test

ls -l /var/ | grep www
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root 4096 Jan 15 23:33 www

ls -l /var/www/test/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7 Jan 15 21:08 index.html
```

Now I have this issue:

```
curl http://example.com/test/
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.5</center>
</body>
</html>
```

```
curl http://example.com/test
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.5</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect to see "Test" when I access `http://example.com/test` or `http://example.com/test/`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Two separate things are happening.

nginx appends the request URI at the end of path of `root` directive when serving the request. In your case, the URL is, `http://example.com/test`, the normalized URI is `/test` and your `root` is `/var/www/test`.

This makes nginx look for `index.html` in `/var/www/test/test/index.html`.

To make nginx server `/var/www/test/index.html`, you need to either use:

```
root /var/www;
```

or

```
alias /var/www/test;
```

Using `root` is the preferred way.

For the `http://example.com/test` part, nginx sends a 301 redirect to `http://example.com/test/` when there is a directory `test` on the server. Your question does not show what is the `root` directive in the upper level, so I don't know in which path the existence of `test` is checked.

Comment: But why am I not seeing 404 for `/var/www/test/test/index.html`?

Comment: Actually nginx returns 403 for `http://example.com/test/` and 404 for `http://example.com/test/index.html` request with your current configuration. Why exactly nginx works like this, I don't know.